# K means library designed for large dataset in python

Tags: python

I find a k means library for large dataset in R (https://www.r-bloggers.com/k-means-clustering-on-big-data/) , may I know is there any similar library in python?

Answer (score 1):

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

Although k-means is not to hard to code.

Comment: K-means is not hard to code, but, it is hard to make it work efficiently in large dataset, I wish to have a one is optimized for large dataset, not sure is this one?

Comment: Yup it is.. you can play with its parameters though